# Replace value in list

Tags: c#, list

hi i have collection list named ~runs~

```
 class CRun {
   int slideQuestion;
   int studentId;
   string answer;
 }

 public static List<CRun> runs = new List<CRun>();
```

this is how i add data to collection list

```
myRun.slideQuestion = 1;
myRun.studentId = 15;
myRun.answer = 2;

0 = { 1, 15, 2}
1 = { 1, 12, 5}
2 = { 2, 15, 3}
3 = { 2, 12, 4}
```

then i have data like this { 1, 15, 1}
i wanna replace list[0] (same slideQuestion & studentID) so it's become

```
**0 = {1, 15, 1}**
1 = { 1, 12, 5}
2 = { 2, 15, 3}
3 = { 2, 12, 4}
```

i wanna make condition like this

```
if ~slideQuestion~ AND ~studentID~ already in list 
    //replace answer in some location
else (add data)
    runs.add(myRun);
```

how to do it?

Comment: `answer` is `string`. Do you want to *replace answer* of *existing question/student* combo? What are the problems? Find an index of list item with needed question/student and replace its answer.

Comment: @Sinatr no answer is int...that is the problem
i can't figure how to find index of list item with have same parameter and replace that answer..can u give me example code maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using linq:

```
var r = runs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.slideQuestion == 10 && c.studentId == 15);
if (r != null)
{
    r.answer = "something";
}
else
{
    runs.Add(new CRun
    {
       slideQuestion = 10,
       studentId = 15,
       answer = "something"
     });   
 }
```

Change your class to this:

```
class CRun {
   public int slideQuestion { get; set; }
   public  int studentId { get; set; }
   public  string answer { get; set; }
}
```

You cannot access the class fields if they are private. Change them to auto-properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to replace the first element in the list:

```
runs[0] = newValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the new slidequestion, student id, and the answer you want to replace are in these variables

```
int slideQuestion = 1;
int studentId = 15;
string newAnswer = "1";
```

Here is how you search for run and update with the new answer if it exists or create a new run

```
var runInList = (from run in runs where run.SlideQuestion == slideQuestion && studentId == studentId select run).FirstOrDefault();

if (runInList != null)
{
    runInList.Answer = newAnswer;
}
else
{
    runs.Add(new CRun { SlideQuestion = slideQuestion, StudentId = studentId, Answer = newAnswer });
}
```

Comment: i will give a shot this solution